# Vue.js with Stomp websocket

Tags: sockets, spring-mvc, vue.js, stomp

I'am developing Spring with Vue.js and I want to use Stomp websockets. I have problem connecting with backend-service. Can anybody help to give me some explanation or some example about how do i connect back-end service and how do i subscribe, how can i pass Authorization header?
I want to use this plugin: [vue-stomp plugin for VueJS.](https://github.com/FlySkyBear/vue-stomp)
And this is my plain JS example:

```
function connect() {
var socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8081/gs-guide-websocket');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
    setConnected(true);
    console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
    stompClient.subscribe('http://localhost:8081/signal/topic/greetings', function (greeting) {
        showGreeting(JSON.parse(greeting.body).content);
    });
});
```

}